# Avoid Too Many Redirects on Root level 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I'm attempting to change the .htaccess on a website such that each page redirects to a specific page on another website. I've managed to get the non-root level pages to redirect to the new domain with no problem, but however I seem to try to redirect from the root of the old website I end up getting a 'too many redirects' problem. This feels pretty key for optimizing someone's site when they've changed from a previous domain, so would be useful to know.

The code I've got working is this:

```
Redirect 301 /my_counselling.html newsite.org.uk/
Redirect 301 /fees_and_contacts.html newsite.org.uk//?page_id=11
Redirect 301 /qualifications.html newsite.org.uk/
Redirect 301 /resources.html newsite.org.uk/
Redirect 301 /abuse.html newsite.org.uk/
Redirect 301 /drug_and_alchol.html newsite.org.uk//?page_id=57
Redirect 301 /lgbt_sexuality.html newsite.org.uk//?page_id=13
Redirect 301 /dyslexia.html newsite.org.uk//?page_id=8
```

But the following attempts to match the ROOT level all fail:

```
Redirect 301 / newsite.org.uk/
```

or

```
RewriteRule oldsite.com/ newsite.org.uk [R=301,L,NC]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ newsite.org.uk/
```

which are suggestions I've read.

This feels like it should be very simple. If I can just get visitors and bots that would have gone to the old site's root to now go to the new site's root I'll be done.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both domains are on the same server, in that case, You'll need to match against the olddomain using a RewriteCondition and then redirect to the newdomain if that condtion is true.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.uk/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```